# Python: efficient way of splitting values read from command line

Tags: python, data-structures

I am reading values from command line. Here the first value is an integer and rest are strings.

Example :
6 tefwz tefwz piygu ezyfo tefwz piygu

Now I would like to save the value 6 in a variable x and
the rest of the strings as a list.

Comment: `x, *rest = "6 tefwz tefwz piygu ezyfo tefwz piygu".split()`

Comment: are you reading using `input()`? Just `split()` the string yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line arguments are accessible via sys.argv

```
import sys

x = int(sys.argv[1])
arg_list = sys.argv[2:]
```